# CMake could not find a package configuration file provided by "PocoDataPostgreSQL"

Tags: c++, postgresql, cmake, poco-libraries

I am getting below set of error while building a project on MAC big sur:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoConfig.cmake:29 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "PocoDataPostgreSQL" with any of the following names:

    PocoDataPostgreSQLConfig.cmake
    pocodatapostgresql-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "PocoDataPostgreSQL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "PocoDataPostgreSQL_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "PocoDataPostgreSQL" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)
```

Below is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(RestAPI)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)


find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
find_package(Poco REQUIRED COMPONENTS Data DataPostgreSQL Foundation JSON Net Zip)


add_executable(RestAPI src/Main.cpp src/Database.cpp src/API.cpp)

target_link_libraries(RestAPI PUBLIC PostgreSQL::PostgreSQL Poco::Data Poco::DataPostgreSQL Poco::Foundation Poco::JSON Poco::Zip Poco::Net)
target_inc`enter code here`lude_directories(RestAPI PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

UPDATE:
After going through some of the similar questions, I have performed below updates on my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/Users/xyz/pocosource/poco/Data/PostgreSQL/cmake/")
include(/Users/xyz/pocosource/poco/Data/PostgreSQL/cmake/PocoDataPostgreSQLConfig.cmake)
#find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
#find_package(Poco REQUIRED COMPONENTS Data DataPostgreSQL Foundation JSON Net Zip)
```

And it leads to below error:

```
CMake Error at /Users/xyz/pocosource/poco/Data/PostgreSQL/cmake/PocoDataPostgreSQLConfig.cmake:4 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    /Users/xyz/pocosource/poco/Data/PostgreSQL/cmake/PocoDataPostgreSQLTargets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (include)
```

Unable to locate PocoDataPostgreSQLTargets.cmake on my system. Did I miss anything at the time of installation of PostgreSQL?

Comment: "Did I miss anything at the time of installation of PostgreSQL?" - Yes, it seems you missed the `DataPostgreSQL` component when install Poco. Pointing CMake to the `PocoDataPostgreSQLTargets.cmake` in the source tree has a little sense: this file should be **installed**, along with the component itself.

Comment: How to install DataPostgreSQL separately?